# Working with many Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, performance, function

I'm currently working with a personal library that's accumulated quite a number of "helper" functions, which are used throughout my architecture for various purposes. Back when there were only a few of them, I kept them in a single file and object so I could access them like so:

```
tools.parseSomething(obj);
```

This has been terribly handy, and keeps the code still somewhat organised and readable. The problem is that the file (and object) containing these methods is growing to an enormous size, and needs a cleanup. I was considering creating separate files for "categories" of functions and placing them in those, so they'd be accessed like:

```
tools.env.getEnvironmentInfo();
```

My concern with this approach is not the readability so much, but the performance of the look-up. From what I've read recently, object look-ups are no longer the *major* bottle-neck they used to be, but I still want my library to be as efficient as possible (readability second).

I also considered having the separate files, but add all of the functions to the parent object so they're still accessible in the original way, but stored separately. The object containing the functions is "static" and exists as a single instance.

My question is, with regards to what I've explained, what would be the most efficient method of storing and using a large amount of helper functions? By efficiency I mean performance, which is the sole area of concern for me at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't exist? I've read that the V8 engine has some nifty functionality behind it to deal with object property look-ups in a smarter way than the typical dictionary-style reference, but I'm not sure that every JS engine does something similar. Surely `something.test()` is faster than `something.inner.more.test()` ?

Comment: While it is true that nested objects are **[slightly slower](http://jsperf.com/object-nesting-access-speed)**, the difference is really negligible at those execution speeds. You'll gain more efficiency by optimizing your functions.

Comment: @Perry It *doesn't exist* [for any meaningful metric in most all code that exists]. Do not waste time with such micro-optimizations. If there is code for which it matters, it still *"doesn't exist"* until there is a performance test-case showing that it does. Without a performance metric there is no way to tell which effect, *if any*, the additional property access has in the grand scheme of things (e.g. exactly which code in exactly which engine under which JIT/optimizations), nor is there a way to demonstrate changes lead to positive improvements in performance.

Comment: @Cerbrus I ran that perf test in Chrome and IE9. While in Chrome the difference is very-much negligible, in IE the extra layer is "21% slower". The library is used a lot in IE, but I guess ~23 million calls is somewhat unlikely in my case..

Comment: @user2864740: Look at the jsPerf I just posted. There is a clear penalty in execution speed when nesting objects deeper. The difference may be insignificant compared to unoptimized functions, but it's there.

Comment: @user2864740: I know it's not representative. I mentioned multiple times that optimizing functions would have a greater benefit. But that doesn't mean the difference ain't there like you said with *"@Perry It doesn't exist"*.

Comment: @user2864740 I understand that in typical usage, the difference may be so small that it would in fact be a waste of time and effort to concentrate on the depth of these functions. What I'm concerned with is the use of such functions in more heavy actions like animations. The reason I ask this question is because I'm in the process of considering what to do here, so as to not have to redo it in the future because of a poor decision now.

Comment: @Perry Again, *there is no "performance problem" until there is an observable performance issue, hopefully backed up with a performance benchmark with real-world usage*. This "optimization" will not affect the greater code design and if it *is* discovered that it is somehow the bottleneck, it can be addressed in the identified bottlenecks (should any exist wrt the usage). Trivially, one could introduce a local variable at the applicable scope. This question is moot wrt the "categories" (better known as "modules" or "namespaces").

Comment: @Cerbrus Ran the same test on Mobile Safari (iPhone 5) to see a "37%" difference across the examples. Like mentioned in my previous comment, recurring function execution (like in animations) could yield some repetition of calls to layered functions. I still don't know if this would present any noticeable performance hit..

Comment: *"there is no "performance problem" until there is an observable performance issue"*
Yea, let's code however we want to, until we run into a deadlock and have to rewrite everything.

Comment: @Cerbrus But there **is *no* "deadlock" or "algorithm complexity" or "core design" issue here**. This question is currently a waste of time. I'm done and am rather disappointing the feeding of these *context-irrelevant* "%" numbers.

Comment: Then stop wasting your time on posting biased advice.

Comment: @user2864740 How are these % differences irrelevant at all? I compared repetitive lookups on different devices and browsers that commonly use the library in question, which revealed a difference in performance. My question was regarding what is the most efficient practice of dealing with such a structure - So the difference in *performance* statistics such as these seems completely relevant to me.

I do understand that they may not matter now (or ever potentially), but they show a difference in performance, which is what I'm curious about.

Comment: @Perry Because it doesn't matter how much you speed up the bit of the code that takes up 0.00..% of the time overall. The question has *not* presented a problem and, IMOHO, you are being mislead in terms of "performance" by these numbers - ["When you microbenchmark, you get a result that is *essentially fictional*.."](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks). As I have stated above, if this "extra look-up" somehow is a performance issue, it can be trivially addressed by adding local variables at the appropriate locations.

Comment: @user2864740 Considering my only use-case that I am currently concerned about (repetitive calls in situations like animation loops) falls under the local variable assignment point you've raised, I feel that this is enough to drop concern over multi-layer object look-ups for now. Judging by what I've seen, there is a performance hit, but it's so negligible that you'd have to be doing something silly to notice it.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for your input - I'll keep everything mentioned here in mind when refactoring my collection of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree that premature optimization is going on here, however that wasn't your question.

I'd assert that instead of thinking in terms of loosely related scriptlets that 'do kind of related things', I'd suggest an richer object  model that can be stateful and perhaps expose the behaviors you need while hiding some optimizations you feel are necessary like caching lookups, etc.

So instead of `getEnvironmentInfo`, why not have an `Environment` instance that has, for example, already fetched some parameters and stored internally so subsequent calls are made faster. From there you can create new environments or whatever other behaviors suit you.

This is just good programming practice in whatever language.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better. +1

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I merely used `getEnvironmentInfo()` as an example, as some "once-off" functions do cache their calculated values. I've tried to "class-ify" as much as possible to keep everything neat and to avoid repetitive processing of the same information, but for now there is still some need for the 'library' of functions I currently have.